# How can i eliminate the squareroot in simultaneous equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to solve this simultaneous equation:
$$7x-(3\sqrt{5})y=9\sqrt{5}$$
and
$$(2\sqrt5)x+y=34$$
 I tried to multiple everything by $$\sqrt5$$ 
And then I got:
$$7x\cdot(\sqrt5)-15y=45$$
and
$$10x+(\sqrt5)\cdot y=34\cdot\sqrt5$$

But from here on i dont know how to make $x$ or $y$ the same, so I could $-$ or $+$ the 2 equations and solve it.

Or even the way I started it was wrong?

Comment: What would happen of you multiplied the second equation by $3\sqrt{5}$ OR divided the first equation by $3\sqrt{5}$?

Answer (score 3):

Begin by multiplying all terms in the first equation by $\sqrt{5},$ as you have done. We have $$7\sqrt{5}x - 15y = 45.$$ Now multiply the second equation by $15$ so that the $y$ terms can be eliminated. This yields $$30\sqrt{5}x + 15y = 510.$$ Adding the two equations yields $$37\sqrt{5}x = 555.$$ We divide to find $\boxed{x = 3\sqrt{5}}.$ Substituting back in, we can find that $\boxed{y = 4}.$

Answer (score 2):

You don'r need to eliminate it. For example, if you multiply the *second* equation by $3\cdot\sqrt 5$, you get the equation
$$30x + (3\sqrt 5) y = 102\sqrt 5$$

and you can add this equation to the first equation to get

$$37 x = 9\sqrt 5 + 102\sqrt 5 = 111\sqrt 5$$

Answer (score 1):

You should just multiply the second equation by $3\sqrt5$ and you get

$30x+3\sqrt5 y=34*3\sqrt5$

You add it to the first equation and get

$37x=111\sqrt5$...

Comment: I don't believe this yields the correct answer.

Comment: @K.Jiang I am pretty sure it does...

Comment: @K.Jiang I did... Please take a deeper look...

Comment: My mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Good start on multiplying things by $\sqrt{5}$. But I'd only do it to the first equation. So you get

$$
7\sqrt{5}x - 15y = 45
$$

$$
2\sqrt{5}x + y = 34
$$
\
Now, go ahead and eliminate the $y$ and you can deal with the $\sqrt{5}$ just with x.

Answer (score 0):

For the integer solution, solve $y$:

$$7x-3\sqrt{5}y=9\sqrt{5}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-3\sqrt{5}y=9\sqrt{5}-7x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$3\sqrt{5}y=-9\sqrt{5}+7x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$3\sqrt{5}y=7x-9\sqrt{5}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=\frac{7x-9\sqrt{5}}{3\sqrt{5}}$$

Now, if you set $x=0$:

$$y=\frac{7\cdot0-9\sqrt{5}}{3\sqrt{5}}=\frac{-9\sqrt{5}}{3\sqrt{5}}=\frac{-9}{3}=-3$$

So the integer solution is:

$$x=0,y=-3$$

Comment: "Now, if you set $x=0$" Hmm, what? Why can one set $x=0$? Actually, $(x,y)=(0,-3)$ *does not* solve the system of two equations the OP asks about, since $(2\sqrt5)0+(-3)\ne34$.